# Instantiate specflow table from text

Tags: c#, specflow, gherkin

**Motivation**

I am writing unittests for Specflow Binding methods/classes. In order to call a Specflow method with a Table parameter I am looking for a easy way to get such a Table instance.

**Requirement**

I'd like to code something like the following

```
TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table t = aMethodologyISearch(""
                      + @"| colHead1 | colHead2 |\n"
                      + @"| value1   | value2   |\n");
```

the method

```
Table aMethodologyISearch(string gherkinTable)
```

should be a simple way to get a Specflow.Table in my unittests from a piece of gherkin string.

Cheers

Comment: I'm very confused. Usually you want to specify the table in the feature file so it is readable, then convert the table into some useful structure in your code so you can use it. Why do you want to to the reverse, this seems crazy to me. What problem are you trying to solve as I feel like there must be a better way that what you are trying.

Comment: so you are writing tests for your tests? What about tests for those tests? Where do you draw the line? I can't see the value in what you want to do, but each to his own...

Answer (score 0):

The `Table` class in specflow is public, and has a constructor which takes an optional list of headers and has a method `AddRow` which allows you to add data to the table. So I imagine you can just create a new table using the split on | char of the first row as the constructor arguments and then call addrown using the result of a string split on | for the remaining lines in the text.

Thought you could probably find the code specflow uses in the codebase with a bit of searching...